# Angular. Load and update modal content based on ID

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-click

I need to load a gallery with a bunch of vimeo iframes. The problem is, if I will try to load all these iframes, the page loading time will be unbearable. So first I am just loading a gallery with ng-repeat:

```
<ul data-ng-controller="WorksCtrl">
  <li data-ng-repeat="work in works">
    <a class="video" data-toggle='modal' data-target="#{{work.modalID}}">
      <img src="{{work.images[0]}}" alt=""/>
      <h2>{{work.title}}</h2>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When user clicks the link, it should open a modal with relevant content, like that:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="{{work.modalID}}">
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{work.html_url}}
  </div>
</div>
```

My JSON file looks like that:

```
[
{
    "id":1,
    "modalID":"video1",
    "title": "Video One",
    "images": [
        "images/video_1.jpg"
    ],
    "html_url": "<iframe src='//player.vimeo.com/video/somevideolink1'></iframe>"
},
{
    "id":2,
    "modalID":"video2",
    "title": "Video Two",
    "images": [
        "images/video_2.jpg"
    ],
    "html_url": "<iframe src='//player.vimeo.com/video/somevideolink2'></iframe>"
}
]
```

How to setup ng-click, so it opens the modal with relevant data? So when I click on a link it should put relevant ID and html_url for the iframe to the modal.

Comment: You will have to use something like `<div class="modal-body" ng-bind-html="work.html_url"></div>`. Make sure you read the intricacies involving security and the `$sce` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Comment: Is it possible to update modal content based on what was clicked, giving that we already have JSON loaded by WorksCtrl. I can't figure out how to construct this. When we click link with {{work.modalID}} it loads html_url of that object.

Comment: Maybe provide a fiddle with the code that does not work...

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, unfortuantely there is nothing to show yet. The code doesn't exist, I am trying to figure out how NOT to load all iframes at once, but only iframe of the object in question. Since we loaded the JSON already, we have all needed data, but now I need to load particluar data - "html_url" into the modal and show it to the user, and I need to do this on click on this "<a class="video"> link. So when user clicks "<a class="video" data-toggle='modal' data-target="#video1">" the html_url of this object is loaded into modal-body. Now I only know how to load all ifames.

Comment: Ok, that is clear now. What are you using for the modals? Anyway, you need to make sure that the template containing the `<iframe>` is not included in the DOM eagerly for each element in the repeat. Angular-ui-bootstrap does this (you provide a template and it attaches it to the DOM only when the dialog is to be shown). Or you can use `ng-if` - *NOT* `ng-show`!